# what is the difference between sp_executesql and option recompile

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can someone tell me the difference between sp_executesql and option recompile.
Both of them creates new plan everytime query is executed.I can create the below stored procedure in 2 ways -- stored procedure like mentioned below or using sp_executesql in stored procedure.

----------Method 1 -------------

```
create procedure test
@var1 int,
@start date,
@end date

with recompile
as
begin

declare @v1 date
declare @v2 date

set @v1 = @var1
set @v2 = @var2

if @var1 > 0
begin
select a.name,b.name
from table1 as a
inner join table2 as b
on a.id = b.id
where a.id <= @var1 and a.date between @v1 and @v2
end

else if @var1 < 0

begin
select a.name,b.name
from table1 as a
inner join table2 as b
on a.id = b.id
where a.id >= @var1 and a.date between @v1 and @v2
end
end
```

----------Method 2 -------------

```
create procedure test
@var1 int,
@start date,
@end date

with recompile
as
begin

declare @v1 date
declare @v2 date
declare @sql nvarchar(100)

set @v1 = @var1
set @v2 = @var2

set @sql = 'if ' + @var1 + ' > 0
begin
select a.name,b.name
from table1 as a
inner join table2 as b
on a.id = b.id
where a.id <= ' + @var1 + ' and a.date between ' + @v1 + ' and ' + @v2 +
' end

else if ' + @var1 + ' < 0

begin
select a.name,b.name
from table1 as a
inner join table2 as b
on a.id = b.id
where a.id >= ' + @var1 + 'and a.date between ' + @v1 + ' and ' +  @v2 + 
' end'

exec sp_executesql @sql
end
```

I have 2 issues here - first, parameter sniffing and second, plan gets reused.For Parameter sniffing I am using local variables @var1 and @var2. The plan will be different for condition if @var1 > 0 and if @var1 < 0. So I force the optimizer to again create the execution Plan by using Option recompile.

Now Can someone tell me why execution plan in the above 2 methods are different. Both methods takes care of parameter sniffing and regenerate Execution plan.

Also can someone tell me the difference between sp_executesql and option recompile. Both work the same way that is both regenerate Execution plan every time query is executed. Which one should be preferred in case records are 1 Million and why?

Comment: What made you think that `sp_executesql` regenerates execution plan every time it runs? Also, `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` is not the same as `CREATE PROCEDURE ... WITH RECOMPILE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> RECOMPILE Indicates that the Database Engine does not cache a query
>   plan for this procedure, forcing it to be compiled each time it is
>   executed. For more information regarding the reasons for forcing a
>   recompile, see Recompile a Stored Procedure. This option cannot be
>   used when FOR REPLICATION is specified or for CLR procedures.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

While sp_executesql

> sp_executesql can be used instead of stored procedures to execute a
>   Transact-SQL statement many times when the change in parameter values
>   to the statement is the only variation. Because the Transact-SQL
>   statement itself remains constant and only the parameter values
>   change, the SQL Server query optimizer is likely to reuse the
>   execution plan it generates for the first execution.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms188001%28v=sql.120%29.aspx